# Does parent process shares cpu registers with child process

Tags: operating-system, cpu, child-process, context-switch

When a child process is created (using fork), it inherits parts of memory image of parent process (program arguments, environment variables, heap and program text etc.). Does it also inherit data in cpu registers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the registers that are visible to the program are copied to the child (e.g. stack pointer). There are other registers that the OS sets (e.g. control registers) that will change, but these registers are not accessible from the child.